# How to find the cartesian equation of $\{z: \operatorname{Arg} z = \frac{\pi }{3}\}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

How to find the cartesian equation of $\{z: \operatorname{Arg} z = \frac{\pi }{3}\}$?

What I have tried so far:

$z= x + iy$ and so substituting $z$ in:

$x + iy = \frac{\pi}{3}$

$3(x+iy) = \pi$

$3x+3iy = \pi$

But I don't understand how to find the cartesian equation from here?

The answer is $y=\sqrt3 x$ but I do not know how to derive that.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $\arg z$ is not $z$. You should consider the polar form of a complex number to get the argument.

Comment: @player3236 do you think you could give me a tip on where to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $z = x+iy \Rightarrow\arg(z) = \tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x} $ or $\color{blue}{\frac{y}{x} = \tan(\arg(z))}$

Answer (score 0):

In polar form we have $z=x+iy=re^{i\theta}=re^{iArg(z)},$ then from Euler's formula we know that $e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta).$

Can you use this to find a relationship between $x$ and $y$?